# conflicts in maven dependencies for sun jersey client

Tags: maven, jersey-client

I have a large project having a number of maven modules under the root module **datastore** , In one of the modules I am using the jersey client dependencies as ,

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
```

[This is the dependency which is to be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us8IT.png).

The Client was working fine.

Then, I copied the same code with same imports of jersey into other multi-module maven project and added the dependencies into pom XML.
But now the code crashes and I found out that the dependencies that are being referred now are different!!

So, I want to know:

How to explicitly specify which dependencies are to be used? (Note: I changed the pom of this new module but it is again getting jersey deps. from parent pom)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your project may have a different version of jersey libraries ,
Because there are a lot of changes in jersey 1.x and jersey 2.x APIs
So instead of getting multiple conflicting dependencies for the same lib , try to modify/upgrade your code to match jersey 2.0 API
[Here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-1.x) is a guide for code migration